# How to share file in Windows Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, sharing, file-sharing

I am using an Amazon EC2 instance running Windows.

How can I share a file to external users that are not in the same network but they have internet access? If there is an option by doing it programmatically, it will be very useful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your situation is not specific to Amazon EC2. The answer would be applicable to *any* Windows computer on the Internet.

The easiest way for a computer to "share a file to external users" would be via a web server. Users could simply click a link in the web browser and the file would download.

However, since you are running on AWS, you might want to **take advantage of Amazon S3**, which is a an object storage service. You could upload the file from the Windows computer to Amazon S3 and then make the file publicly available via a URL. This way, your users will be able to access the file without having to connect to the Windows computer. It would also be more reliable and could handle more traffic than the Windows computer. You can programmatically upload to an Amazon S3 bucket.

Comment: Thank u. I will share a file that is regularly updating in some min.ie taking live values.. So file should be regularly updated and save in shared place and also link will be same. Link  should not be change,

Comment: That sounds like a good use-case for storing it in Amazon S3. Do you need your users to authenticate, or are you willing to make the file publicly accessible? If the need to authenticate, how will you manage their access permissions?

Comment: thanks. I want that llink to be embedded in .net application. so that users wont see link  but get data from link

Comment: If you are putting something into an application, then it needs to be reliable and highly-available. Amazon S3 would certainly be more suitable for this task than serving from a single computer. You might also want to put a domain name on the Amazon S3 bucket. See: [Configuring a static website using a custom Domain registered with Route 53 - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html)

Comment: Thank u. i will try out and get back to you .